# How can I set the order in which discrete objects are instantiated?

Tags: scala, object

I wrote an object `PathGraph` which implements a graph of `Node`s and various useful functions, which I intend to use for pathfinding in a simple tower defense game. I also wrote a class `Path` which implements Dijkstra's algorithm, and each non-static in-game unit has a `Path`.

The problem I am running into is that when I run the application, the code executes the code to initialize the units and, in doing so, initialize a path for each creep before building the PathGraph object (confirmed using Eclipse Scala debugger and println statements). Unfortunately however, the code to generate a path requires that the `PathGraph` object, and specifically the `path` variable (`var` so that I can point to a new path if the map gets updated, etc.), be initialized.

How should I fix this problem with my code? PathGraph code pasted below for reference.

```
object PathGraph {
  private val graph:Array[Array[Node]] = buildAndFillGraph()

  //val nodeDist:Double = MainGame.pixelsPerIteration
  val nodeDist = .5
  val numXNodes = (MainGame.gamePanelWidth.toDouble / nodeDist).toInt
  val numYNodes = (MainGame.gamePanelHeight.toDouble / nodeDist).toInt
  val defaultInfinity = 99999

  //build every Nodes adjacent nodes
  val angle = 45
  val minHeight = 0
  val minWidth = 0
  val maxHeight = MainGame.gamePanelSize.height //game panel y value starts at 0 at TOP
  val maxWidth = MainGame.gamePanelSize.width
  val numPossibleAdjacentNodes = 360 / angle //360 degrees, 45 degree angle between every potentially adjacent Node
  val hypotenuseLength = math.sqrt((nodeDist * nodeDist) + (nodeDist * nodeDist))



  def buildGraphArray(): Array[Array[Node]] = {
    println("numXNodes/nodeDist.toInt: " + (numXNodes.toDouble / nodeDist).toInt + "\n")
    //build every Node in the graph
    val lgraph = 
      (for (x <- 0 until (numXNodes / nodeDist).toInt) yield {
      (for (y <- 0 until (numYNodes / nodeDist).toInt) yield {
        new Node(x.toDouble * nodeDist, y.toDouble * nodeDist)//gives lgraph(x,y) notation
      }).toArray //convert IndexedSeqs to Arrays
    }).toArray//again

    lgraph
  }

  def buildAndFillGraph():Array[Array[Node]] = {
    val lgraph = buildGraphArray()//Ar[Ar[Node]]
    println("lgraph built")
    lgraph.map(x => x.map(y => y.setAdjacentNodes(lgraph)))
    //set the adjacent nodes for all nodes in the array
    if (lgraph.size != numXNodes*numYNodes) println("numXNodes*numYNodes: " + numXNodes*numYNodes)
    else MainGame.pathGraphBuilt = true
    lgraph

  }

  def getGraph() = graph

  def toBuffer(): mutable.Buffer[Node] = graph.flatten.toBuffer

  def toArray(): Array[Node] = graph.flatten
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to improve the code:

- Do not use static variables. Your `PathGraph` should be a class, not an object. `MainGame. pathGraphBuilt` is also a static variable that you can replace with a builder - see the next point.
- Use a Builder pattern to differentiate between *things that build* and the *end result*. Your PathGraph logic will mostly go into the builder. Something along these lines:

-

```
case class PathGraphBuilder(nodeDist: Double, numXNodes: Double /* and so on */) {
  def apply: PathGraph = buildAndFillGraph
  def buildGraphArray = ...
  def buildAndFillGraph = ...
}

class PathGraph(underlyingGraph: Array[Array[Node]]) {
  def toBuffer(): mutable.Buffer[Node] = underlyingGraph.flatten.toBuffer

  def toArray(): Array[Node] = underlyingGraph.flatten
}
```